# check if string values of a column in a dataframe start with string elements of a tuple (other than str.startswith)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, startswith

I have a pandas dataframe column with random values (`"457645","458762496","1113423453"...`) and I need to check if these values start with the elements of a tuple `("323","229","111")`.

In this case, it should be true for `"1113423453"`.

I have tried `df[column].str.startswith(tuple)`, which works fine; but for a large amount of data (2M df rows and 3K tuple elements) it becomes much slower (around 28 seconds) compared to 10K df rows and 3K tuple elements (1.47 seconds).

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: actually it's 100K my bad. Anyway, what i meant is for a smaller set it doesnt really affect the performance, but when it comes to larger sets of data i'm searching for a way (if possible) to get it done faster.

Comment: Even with 100K, 2M rows @ 28 sec is almost exactly the same speed with 100K rows @ 1.47 sec.

Comment: i know, i get that.. but i'm searching for a more efficient way to do it if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried `df[column].str.startswith(tuple)`, which works fine … but i'm searching for a more efficient way to do it if it's possible

Since `startswith()` isn't optimized for a large amount of prefix strings and does just a linear search through them, using a binary search may be more efficient here. For this, we need the prefixes sorted.

```
from bisect import bisect_right
s = sorted(tuple)
df[column].apply(lambda str: str.startswith(s[bisect_right(s, str)-1]))
```

> is it possible to extract the prefix into a new column of the dataframe?

Yes, e. g. with this function:

```
def startwiths(str):
    prefix = s[bisect_right(s, str)-1]
    if str.startswith(prefix): return prefix

df['new column'] = df[column].apply(startwiths)
```

Comment: thanks! this works much faster.. is it possible to extract the prefix into a new column of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes - I amended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Armali only works on Strings with the same length. If you have Strings with variable lengths, you need to group by length and then use Armalis algorithm. It's still MUCH faster than the build-in solution on big DataFrames.

```
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd 
import random
from pandas._testing import rands_array
from bisect import bisect_right

# create random strings
def zufallsdaten(anz):   
    result = pd.DataFrame()         
    result['string_A'] = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, anz)   
    result['string_B'] = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, anz)    
    def bearbeite_element( skalar ):
        l = random.randint(2,5)
        return skalar[0:l] 
    result['string_B'] = result['string_B'].apply(bearbeite_element)
    return result

# create data to search in
manystrings = pd.DataFrame(zufallsdaten(1000000)['string_A'])

# create data to search
search_me   = pd.DataFrame(zufallsdaten(100000)['string_B'].drop_duplicates())



# fast startswith alternative. Finds the longest / shortest matching fragment and writes it into the field foundfieldname.
# if find_identical, the strings may not be identical.  
def fast_startswith(df, searchfieldname, foundfieldname, searchseries, find_longest=True, find_identical=True):
    
    # startswith alternative, works only if all strings in searchme have the same length. Also returns the matching fragment
    def startwiths(data, searchme, find_identical):
        prefix = searchme[bisect_right(searchme, data)-1]
        if ((data!=prefix) or find_identical ) and data.startswith(prefix): 
            return prefix    
        
    search = pd.DataFrame(searchseries)
    search.columns = ['searchstring']
    search['len'] = search.searchstring.str.len()
    grouped = search.groupby('len')
    lengroups = grouped.agg(list).reset_index().sort_values('len', ascending=find_longest)  
    result = df.copy()
    result[foundfieldname] = None
    for index, row in lengroups.iterrows():
        result[foundfieldname].update(result[searchfieldname].apply(startwiths, searchme=sorted(row.searchstring), find_identical=find_identical)  )  
        #result[foundfieldname] = result[foundfieldname].fillna(  result[searchfieldname].apply(startwiths, searchme=sorted(row.searchstring))  )
    return result
    
    

def fast_startswith2(df, searchfieldname, foundfieldname, searchseries):

    # startswith alternative, works only if all strings in searchme have the same length. Also returns the matching fragment
    def startwiths(data, searchme):
        prefix = searchme[bisect_right(searchme, data)-1]
        if data.startswith(prefix): return prefix    
    
    def grouped_startswith(searchme, data):
        data[foundfieldname].update(data[searchfieldname].apply(startwiths, searchme=sorted(searchme.searchstring)))
        return list(searchme.searchstring)   
    
    search = pd.DataFrame(searchseries)
    search.columns = ['searchstring']
    search['len'] = search.searchstring.str.len()
    grouped = search.groupby('len')     
    result = df.copy()
    result[foundfieldname] = None
    grouped.apply(grouped_startswith, data=result)
    return result    



%%time 
mask = manystrings.string_A.str.startswith(tuple(search_me.string_B))
result0 = manystrings[mask]
# result0: built-in startswith
# Wall time: 1min 6s 



%%time
df = fast_startswith(manystrings, 'string_A', 'found', search_me.string_B) 
mask = df.found.notnull()
result1 = df[mask]   
#print( result0.shape[0],   result1.shape[0])
assert result0.shape[0] == result1.shape[0]

# result1: iterate through groups of strings with same length.
# also returns the matching fragment
# Wall time: 6.33 s



%%time
df = fast_startswith2(manystrings, 'string_A', 'found', search_me.string_B) 
mask = df.found.notnull()
result2 = df[mask]    
#print( result0.shape[0],   result2.shape[0])
assert result0.shape[0] == result2.shape[0]

# result2: apply fast startswith method on groups of strings with same length
# also returns the matching fragment
# Wall time: 5.94 s



# differences? May occur if you use find_longest=False
result = pd.merge(result1,result2, on='string_A', suffixes=('_1','_2'))
mask = (result.found_1 != result.found_2)
result[mask]



# search self
df = fast_startswith(search_me, 'string_B', 'found', search_me.string_B, find_identical=False) 
mask = df.found.notnull()
df[mask]
```

Comment: I saw your post by pure coincidence. I'd like to evaluate it, but that's hard without the missing pieces.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I edited the post so the code should be complete now.

Comment: Indeed the approach with `bisect_right` as is doesn't work if the tuple elements are of different lengths and one element is the start of the next one, e. g. with elements `AI` and `AIKHB0` in `search_me`, the string `AIljP9udNn` is not found in `manystrings`.

Comment: I played around with it a bit and I didn't understand the algorithm. bisect_right has two additional parameters hi and lo, do they help?

Comment: _The parameters lo and hi may be used to specify a subset of the list which should be considered_ - that won't help, we must search in the whole list. The algorithm is just that `bisect_right` is used to quickly find the one element among the sorted tuple elements which is closest to the current `'string_fixlen'`, so that only this one tuple element has to be tested with `startswith`. But this fails if (as in my example) another element (`AIKHB0`) is closer to the the `'string_fixlen'` (`AIljP9udNn`) than the correct element (`AI`).

Comment: This could be corrected by also taking elements in the vicinity of that returned by `bisect_right` into account.

Comment: @GhaFldP - Your approach is good; you just have two errors in `s = sorted(search_me.string_B)`
    `data['found3'] = data.string_A.apply(startwiths, searchme=s)`: 1. typo in `search_me` 2. In each length group run, the column `found3` is overwritten and the results from preceding groups are lost; you could use `.update()` here. Correct: `s = sorted(searchme.string_B)`
    `data['found3'].update(data.string_A.apply(startwiths, searchme=s))` - but we have to initialize `manystrings['found3'] = None` before the first run.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the fantastic fast solution! I put it all to a helper, see the edited post. The interface is a little bit ugly but it's MUCH faster on my big DataFrames.